# Enhance awk script by printing top 5 occurring data elements from each column

Tags: csv, awk

I have an awk script that processes a csv file and produces a report that counts the number of rows for each column, named in the header field, that contain data /[A-Za-z0-9]/. What I would like to do is enhance the script and print the top 5 most duplicated data elements in each column.

Here is sample data:

```
Food|Type|Spicy
Broccoli|Vegetable|No
Lettuce|Vegetable|No
Spinach|Vegetable|No
Habanero|Vegetable|Yes
Swiss Cheese|Dairy|No
Milk|Dairy|No
Yogurt|Dairy|No
Orange Juice|Fruit|No
Papaya|Fruit|No
Watermelon|Fruit|No
Coconut|Fruit|No
Cheeseburger|Meat|No
Gorgonzola|Dairy|No
Salmon|Fish|
Apple|Fruit|No
Orange|Fruit|No
Bagel|Bread|No
Chicken|Meat|No
Chicken Wings|Meat|Yes
Pizza||No
```

This is the current script that SiegeX has substantially contributed:

```
$ cat matrix2.awk 
NR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    head[i]=$i
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
  {
    if($i && !arr[i,$i]++)
      n[i]++
    if(arr[i,$i] > 1)
      f[i]=1
  }
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=length(head);i++) {
    printf("%-6d%s\n",n[i],head[i])
    if(f[i]) {
      for(x in arr) {
        split(x,b,SUBSEP)
        if(b[1]==i && b[2])
          printf("% -6d %s\n",arr[i,b[2]],b[2])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the current output:

```
$ awk -F "|" -f matrix2.awk testlist.csv 
20    Food
6     Type
 6     Fruit
 4     Vegetable
 3     Meat
 1     Fish
 4     Dairy
 1     Bread
2     Spicy
 17    No
 2     Yes
```

And this is the desired output:

```
$ awk -F "|" -f matrix2.awk testlist.csv 
20    Food
6     Type
 6     Fruit
 4     Vegetable
 4     Dairy
 3     Meat
 1     Fish
2     Spicy
 17    No
 2     Yes
```

The only thing left that I would like to add is a general function that limits each columns output to the top 5 most duplicated fields. As mentioned below, a columnar version of sort |uniq -c |sort -nr |head -5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script is both extensible and scalable as it will work with an arbitrary number of columns. **Nothing** is hardcoded

```
awk -F'|' '
NR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    head[i]=$i
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
  {
    if($i && !arr[i,$i]++)
      n[i]++
    if(arr[i,$i] > 1)
      f[i]=1
  }
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=length(head);i++) {
    printf("%-32s%d\n",head[i],n[i])
    if(f[i]) {
      for(x in arr) {
        split(x,b,SUBSEP)
        if(b[1]==i && b[2])
          printf("    %-28s%d\n",b[2],arr[i,b[2]])
      }
    }
  }
}' infile
```

#### Output

```
$ ./report
Food                            9
Type                            5
    Meat                        2
    Bread                       1
    Vegetable                   2
    Fruit                       2
    Fish                        1
Spicy                           2
    Yes                         2
    No                          6
```

Comment: This is brilliant! The only addition I would be grateful to see is limiting the output to the top 5 most frequently occurring duplicates in column. On files with thousands of records, listing all the elements becomes too much. An awk  function equivalent to: sort |uniq -ci |sort -nr |head -5 # for each column would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, but something to get you started -

```
awk -F"|" '
NR>1{
        a[$1]++;
        b[$2]++;
        c[$3]++}
END{
        print "Food\t\t\t" length(a); 
        print "Type\t\t\t" length(b); 
        for (x in b) 
            if (x!="") 
            {
                printf ("\t%-16s%s\n",x,b[x]);
            }
        print "Spicy\t\t\t" length(c); 
        for (y in c) 
            if (y!="") 
            {
                printf ("\t%-16s%d\n",y,c[y])
            }
}' testlist.csv
```

#### TEST:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat testlist.csv 
Food|Type|Spicy
Broccoli|Vegetable|No
Jalapeno|Vegetable|Yes
Salmon|Fish|
Apple|Fruit|No
Orange|Fruit|No
Bagel|Bread|No
Chicken|Meat|No
Chicken Wings|Meat|Yes
Pizza||No

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F"|" 'NR>1{a[$1];b[$2]++;c[$3]++}END{print "Food\t\t\t" length(a); print "Type\t\t\t"length(b); for (x in b) if (x!="") printf ("\t%-16s%s\n",x,b[x]) ;print "Spicy\t\t\t"length(c); for (y in c) if (y!="") {printf ("\t%-16s%d\n",y,c[y])}}' testlist.csv 
Food                9
Type                6
    Fruit           2
    Vegetable       2
    Bread           1
    Meat            2
    Fish            1
Spicy               3
    Yes             2
    No              6
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am still working on, and seeking help for, a more general solution that does not have field names hardcoded into the script.